# Redux toolkit slice. Pure functions inside field reducers

Tags: redux-toolkit

Sup ya. Just wanna specify can we use it? I think we can just wanna be sure 100%

https://codesandbox.io/s/redux-toolkit-state-new-array-4sswi?file=/src/redux/slices/slice.js:111-425

```
const someSlice = createSlice({
  name: "someSlice",
  initialState: {
    users: [],
    status: ""
  },
  reducers: {
    actionSuccess: (state, { payload }) => {
      state.users = payload.users;
    },
    actionFailure: (state) => {
      // can we use here function?
      statusHandler(state)
    }
  }
});
```

Answer (score 0):

A reducer should not trigger any side effects.  That is, it should not do anything other than change the contents of the state.  So you should not call a `statusHandler` which would trigger external effects.

If your `statusHandler` function does nothing but update the state, that does seem to work in my testing and I'm not aware of any reason why it shouldn't be okay.

Redux Toolkit uses [Immer](https://immerjs.github.io/immer/docs/introduction) behind the scenes to deal with immutable updates, so this question basically boils down to whether these two functions, `updatedInline` and `updatedExternally`, are equivalent.  They are, as far as I can tell.

```js
const {produce} = immer;

const initialState = {
  status: ''
};

const updatedInline = produce( initialState, draft => {
  draft.status = 'failed';
})

const mutateStatus = (state) => {
  state.status = 'failed';
}

const updatedExternally = produce( initialState, mutateStatus )

console.log("Updated Inline: \n", updatedInline);
console.log("Updated Externally: \n", updatedExternally);
```

```html
<script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/immer@8.0.1/dist/immer.umd.production.min.js"></script>
```